# can't upload new theme in joomla

Tags: templates, joomla

I use joomla and I am beginner at Joomla platform.I go to Extension Manager: Install.  When trying to install new templates, its writing "Unknown Archive type". Archive type is .zip. I try to install by this way/ "Upload Package File", but I can't . And also, the directory Templates is writeable 777 .
What's the problem?
Thanks beforehand

Comment: is it a custom template? i mean did you develop the template from scratch?

Comment: If you are using Joomla 1.5 I would say you extract the template in a folder, upload that folder to your templates directory with FTP ... It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Uncompress the file into a new folder.
2. Then compress that folder into a .zip format.
3. Now upload the package file again and you should not get that error again.

Make sure you don't have an "zip" or "tar.gz" files inside the zip file you are uploading. Also never change folders and file permissions to 777. All newbies make this and it a very serious security problem for your app. Ask your host to do all folders 755 and files 644 as @Lodder said.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to change the permission of other directories too. Off course, it can be other things.

Check out this link: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2300161/Joomla-v-1-5-Template-Installation-Troubleshooting-Manual. It is for version 1.5.

Comment: directories shouldn't have to be changed. folder should always be set to 755 and files 644

Comment: You are right. According to that link, only the following directories: /joomlaroot/templates and /joomlaroot/tmp have to change their permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can think of, is that you need to unzip the ZIP before uploading. It is possible you have other zip files inside the main one, hence the `Unknown Archive type` error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. The problem was I was trying to upload a .rar file. For some reason this is not supported by joomla.